# DLL Reference Needs to Be added again and again?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a C++ project for which I have written a CLI wrapper so that it can be used in some C# projects.

My problem is that when I compile the CLI project each time, the reference in the C# projects has to be deleted and added again manually.

I reference this project in some 5 places and the CLI project is required to be modified and compiled often. Is there anything to do, so that I can avoid this? Its kind a boring deleting the reference and adding 'em again. Well, I am a bit lazy!!

Comment: Can you explain why "the reference in the C# projects has to be deleted and added again manually"? How are you adding the reference?

Comment: Next time use the Project tab in the Add Reference dialog.

Comment: @AVIDeveloper: I am adding by Right Clicking on the Project> Add Reference and Browsing for the DLL.@HansPassant: It works. Thanks.

Comment: have you check the build sequence or dependency in the solution?